# Is is possible to use django's GEOSGeometry as an independent product

Tags: python, django, gis, geos

Is there a way to use django's GEOSGeometry without installing all of Django? I know it is possible to use it independently and I could trim out the rest of Django, but since it is quite useful, I wonder if somebody did this already. Basically, I want to easy_install GEOSGeometry.

Comment: Our firm developed this, since we couldn't find it https://github.com/meteogrid/pygeos

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get GEOSGeometry that way, "easy_install Shapely" gets you a package that's equivalent. See http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/README.html.

Comment: Yes, I want Shapely plus srid. We are working on it now, in case anyone is interested.